# Failed to start : Class not found: "class name" - JUnit, Robolectric

Tags: android-studio, automation, junit4, robolectric

Am developing unit tests using JUnit and Robolectric, occasionally my Android Studio throw this error - **Failed to start : Class not found: "class name". Process finished with exit code 1**. Why is this happening. Sometimes restarting my studio works, sometimes it works right away.

**EDIT** :  I see this issue when I switch between Android app and Android Unittests

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and rebuilding it before running test cases.

Comment: no luck.. I already tried that. Sometimes it works well w/o doing anything.